# The following files have NOT been resolved when using mvn install?

Tags: spring, maven-2

greetings all
i have a web application using (spring-hibernate) frameworks
and when tried to build the application with maven2 using the command mvn install
i get a build successful with the following note:

The following files have NOT been resolved:

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:java-source:sources:2.7.7
[INFO]    com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:java-source:sources:1.2.1
[INFO]    com.sun.jmx:jmxri:java-source:sources:1.2.1
[INFO]    commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:java-source:sources:1.2.2
[INFO]    commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:java-source:sources:3.1
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:java-source:sources:1.1.0.jboss
[INFO]    hibernate-commons-annotations:hibernate-commons-annotations:java-source:sources:3.0.0.GA
[INFO]    hsqldb:hsqldb:java-source:sources:1.8.0.2
[INFO]    javassist:javassist:java-source:sources:3.4.GA
[INFO]    javax.jms:jms:java-source:sources:1.1
[INFO]    net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:java-source:sources:20040917
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-commons-csv:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-analyzers:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-core:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-highlighter:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-queries:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-snowball:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.solr:solr-lucene-spellchecker:java-source:sources:1.3.0
[INFO]    org.apache.velocity:velocity:java-source:sources:1.5
[INFO]    org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:java-source:sources:3.1.0
[INFO]    quartz:quartz:java-source:sources:1.6.0
[INFO]    stax:stax-api:java-source:sources:1.0.1
```

what does this mean ?

Comment: Have you run Maven in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like output from the maven-dependency-plugin and the 'sources' goal -- it looks like someone has configured the Maven build to pull source artifacts.  What this output means is that Maven was unable to find source artifacts in any Maven2 repositories.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html

Without being able to see it, I am assuming that your compilation and packaging was successful regardless of these messages.

Comment: This sounds like the problem. We could verify this assumption if sword101 posted his pom.xml or even just the maven-dependency-plugin configuration section.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) when you set the execution block when you include a goal to check/list the dependencies while you issue the maven install command.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>source</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You error means one of dependencies is not resolved properly. See all the [goals under the maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) which contains many other goals to help you manage the version you declare in your POM.